# Как сохранить информацию при смене буферов в OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, glut

Пытаюсь написать на C с помощью GLUT'a ["Жизнь" Конуэя](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0_%C2%AB%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8C%C2%BB). Как я понял для движения "организмов" мне надо обработать входной буфер и записать изменения в другой при этом обнулив исходный, и т.д. по кругу (поправьте если не прав). **Сам вопрос:** каким образом запомнить информацию переданную во входящий буфер, чтобы потом с ней можно работать?

P.S. Заранее прошу прощения за возможно неправильные формулировки предложений.

Comment: OpenGL тут не при чем. Он только для рисования. Все расчеты стоит делать либо на CPU, либо в OpenCL или аналоге.

Comment: Если речь о двойной буферизации вывода, то на этом этапе вам нужно знать о ней только то, что эти буферы нужно не забывать переключать соответствующей командой после каждого кадра. Для `life` вам нужно просто держать в памяти один текущий массив (или более подходящую структуру), а изменения вносить уже в новый, который после этого станет текущим.

Comment: а как же рендер в текстуру а на следующем шаге ее на вход?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ вряд ли именно это требуется ОПу :)

Comment: @extrn ну незнаю, как раз game of life очень просто таким образом сделать :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Прямо вот пиксели использовать в качестве ячеек данных? Мещанство :) Да и вообще, прямоугольный массив не особо подходящая структура для оптимального алгоритма: слишком много холостых проверок, да и поле можно реализовать только ограниченное/замкнутое.

Comment: https://jameshfisher.com/2017/10/22/webgl-game-of-life/

Comment: @extrn это же память и Вам решать что там лежит, клетки так клетки =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я не понял ничего про рендер и текстуры, т.к. совсем новичок в openGL, так что даже не знаю как что-то держать в памяти кроме массивов обычных (1 семестр = полный 0), можете мне подсказать каким образом можно вернуть координаты курсора мыши? Я знаю о существовании glutPassiveMotionFunc() но не понимаю как в нее подаются координаты и как их можно вернуть (если на вход даже начальные не подаются)?
С помощью этой функции я бы хотел закрашивать квадраты <=>"клетки" на сетке (которую я нарисовал из GL_LINES).